# Visual Studio 2010 Profesional edition and CPU Usage

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm developing web application, when trying to debug the application suddenly CPU usage goes to 100% for 15-20 minutes even sometimes it takes 30 minute too. It's very frustrating.

System specification
 
Windows seven 32 bit
3GB RAM

I had already googled it but not found any proper solution.

Comment: Do you have any extension added to your VS? Try to remove them selectively

Comment: Just one Solution Loader to solve this problem. Removed it and problem remains as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cleaning the solution?

in my case, high CPU usage started out of nowhere (WPF project). Restarts of Visual Studio didn't help, neither disabling/uninstalling addons. But Cleaning the solution did help!